# How to delete total div content using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to delete the last textarea in a div.

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- question 1st box starts here -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="questionparts">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Questions</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="questions0" id="questions0" placeholder="Questions" style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="questionshowp">
                <h4 class="page-title">Multiple Choice</h4>
                <h6>Your audience can select from these answers:</h6>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="questions1" id="questions1" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text">
                    <div class="secondsec">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="line-height:12px;"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="line-height:12px;"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- question 1st box end here -->

    <!-- question 2nd box starts here -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="questionparts">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Questions</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="questions0" id="questions0" placeholder="Questions" style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="questionshowp">
                <h4 class="page-title">Multiple Choice</h4>
                <h6>Your audience can select from these answers:</h6>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="questions1" id="questions1" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text">
                    <div class="secondsec">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="line-height:12px;"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="line-height:12px;"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- question 2nd box end here -->
</div>
```

Here I need to delete the last textarea ('in this case 2nd box') always. Check javascript below.

```
function deleteQuestionField(){
    var textareas = $('#container textarea');
    console.log('hii',textareas);
  if (textareas.length !== 0) {
    textareas.last().remove();
  }
}
```

This function is called from a button click event but its not deleting the last textarea.

Comment: What do you mean by _total div_ ?

Comment: all codes present inside `<!-- question 2nd box starts here -->` and `<!-- question 2nd box end here -->`.

Comment: Can't you just put a _div_ around the second box and remove it based on the _divs_ id?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use jQuery's `.remove()` ([see here for more info](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)):

Give your div that you want to remove a unique `id` and then call it:

**HTML:**

```
 ....
 <!-- question 2nd box starts here -->
        <div class="col-md-4" id="someUniqueId"> 
 ....
```

**Javascript:**

```
function deleteQuestionField(){
    var textareas = $('#container textarea');
    console.log('hii',textareas);
  if (textareas.length !== 0) {
    $("#someUniqueId").remove(); //This will remove the unique id element
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the html() function in jQuery
http://api.jquery.com/html/ to remove all codes between an element

The remove() function you used delete the selected element

If you want to delete the content of the textarea, try to use the val() function instead.http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
$('textarea').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly *if the first textarea is not empty you want to remove the second 'box'* . If this is the case you should select the *first* textarea and not textarea *in general* (I assume)

firstly *add* an **ID** to the second div `<div class="col-md-4" id="remove_this">` and call the **ID** in the *remove* function

So probably it would be something like:

```
function deleteQuestionField(){
    var textareas = $('#questions0'); //if you want general just use textarea ( `$('#container textarea');`)
    console.log('hii',textareas);
  if (textareas.length !== 0) {
    $("#remove_this").remove();
  }
}
```

> Documentation about the `.remove` function [HERE](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete total div ,but you are making delete only textarea element

```
textareas.last().remove();
//change above code to like below ,it will delete the whole div
$(".col-md-4").last().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery

```
$("#item_id").empty();
```

It works